# Getopt: A flag using with multiple optargs

Tags: c, bash, getopt

How can I use two arguments for one flag?

For example:

```
./xampl -c foo bar
```

would return:

```
foobar
```

I've looked a the source code of gnu cat and freebsd ls, but could not find any leads

I'm a C novice and a competent bash scripter.

Comment: This is a highly nonstandard option syntax; if you really want that, you'll pretty much have to write the parsing code yourself. I'm not sure why you want this, but I'd recommend trying to find a more standard way to accomplish the actual goal.

Comment: There are argument parsers that'll handle that (I've written one of them, but it isn't generally available), but they're few and far between.  Most programs that use that technique for handling arguments also hand-code the argument parsing loop.  I don't think that's a good idea.  So, as already stated, it isn't normal.  However, I wrote my parser to match the requirements of some perfectly horrible hand-coded argument parsing, and that was one of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `getopt` stuff has no way to do this, it allows for single-argument additions to an option (with `:`) like `-cfoo` (part of the option argument) or `-c foo` (in the next argument). This can also be optional if you use `::` though I believe it then has to be an extension of the option argument itself, not a separate argument.

It has no way to take more than one argument after the option argument and combine them into a single option. You can surround them with quotes to force it into a *single* argument, such as:

```
-c "foo bar"
```

but that won't remove the spaces. Of course, there's nothing to stop you specifying *directly* what you seem to want, with a slightly modified:

```
-c foobar
```

In other words, I'm not clear why you actually *need* them to be separate, especially since you're going to combine them anyway.

No doubt you could *modify* `getopt` to do this such as allowing for something like `abc[2,collapse]` (rather than `abc:`) to specify that `-c` needs two arguments which should have spaces removed between them. But that seems like a fair bit of work for something it may just be easier to work around.